# Proving uniqueness

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry this is such a trivial question, but I'd like to check my understanding on this subject before proceeding.

Suppose that we have the quantity $x+a=b$ where $x$ is a variable, and we wish to show that the solution to such an equation is unique. Is the following correct?:

To prove this we assume that the solution is not unique, and instead there is a set of solutions that satisfy the equation $x+a=b$. Then, let $\alpha, \beta$ be any two elements from this set of solutions such that $$\alpha +a =b, \qquad \beta +a=b$$ and hence, $$\alpha +a =\beta +a \Rightarrow \alpha = \beta$$
Now, for this equality to hold for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that we choose from the set of solutions to the equation $x+a=b$, it must be that the set only contains a single, unique element (as this is the only way that the equality $\alpha = \beta$ will hold for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that we choose from the set of solutions).

(Is this analogous to saying that any two values, chosen arbitrarily from a set of values satisfying a given property, can only be equivalent if they are in fact the same value?)

Sorry this is a little convoluted, just trying to get my head around proving uniqueness of a quantity.

Comment: Your intuition seems correct. I would just say that to show uniqueness you don't exactly assume the solution is not unique. You just take two values that solve the equation and show they have to be equal. It's a subtle and probably unimportant point, but that's how I've always thought of it.

Comment: Right, you are correct. And you do not have to say sorry all the time :). Take easy and enjoy mathematics.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer Thanks :) I do have an unfortunate habit of using the "s-word" over zealously. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @candido Ah, ok thanks for the info. Is the rest of my reasoning correct though as to why the equality of any two values (that satisfy the equation) implies a unique solution? Can this same argument be applied to proving that the identity element and inverse elements of a group are unique?

Comment: The essence of your question is "How do I prove a set $S$ has only a single element?" A usual version is a slight variant of your method: you suppose that $p, q \in S$, and show that (because of some other things in the problem), $p = q$. To show a set has two elements, you show that there are $p, q \in S$, with $p \ne q$, and that for any $r \in S$, either $r = p$ or $r = q$. You can probably generalize from here, but in practice showing "no elements" or "one element" or "two elements" is about as far as you'll usually need to go. I don't think I've ever proved a set has exactly 3 elements.

Comment: @John Thanks John. Yes, I was really trying to justify in my mind from considering a priori a set of possibly infinite number of solutions, how one shows that there is actually only one. So, am I correct in saying that you choose two arbitrary elements from the set $S$ (i.e. $p,q \in S$, following your example) and show that in fact $p=q$. Hence, for this equality to hold for any two elements $p,q \in S$, it must be that there is actually only a single, unique element in $S$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The proof is a little less verbose if you don't mention the possible infinitude of the set, but just say "let $p$ and $q$ be elements of the solution set $S$; we'll show that $p = q$, and thus that $S$ has only one element." (For this to be correct, you need to have shown that $S$ is not empty; otherwise the hypothesis ("p and q are in S") is false, and the rest of your proof is useless; in almost all proofs, the proof that there's at LEAST one element happens sort of naturally along the way.)

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks very much for your help. Yes, I was really trying to figure it out leading up to proving that the identity element of a group is unique (so, in this case, proof of existence of at least one element follows from the group axioms). I feel I have a better intuition for the concept now.