# Direct Sum Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right Book and I am on the part about the direct sum. He gives the following proposition:
[image]

When he assumes that $a$ and $b$ hold to prove that the proof gives the completeness part of iff, he has to prove that these make the vectors add such that the sum of vectors can only be represented uniquely. Here is his proof:

[image]

I understand that this means the sum is represented uniquely with two but what about with three. I feel that if it works for two it would have to work for three but I don't know why. For example $(1, 0, 0) - (1, 0, 0) - (0, 0, 0) = 0$ but $(1, 0, 0)$ does not equal $(0, 0, 0)$ or in another case $(1, 1, 0) - (1, 0, 0) - (0, 1, 0) = 0$ but none of these equal each other and they still sum to zero so that $0=(a-b-c)$; this could be extended to be like the proofs that $0 = (a_1-b_1-c_1) + (a_2-b_2-c_2) + ... + (a_n-b_n-c_n)$. What am I missing or not understanding?

Thanks,
Jackson

Also I read some of the related questions such as [Proving uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916603/proving-uniqueness) but in the comments it assumed that the set was only of one or two elements.

Comment: Each term in his sum is from a different summand. In your first example the first two terms are from the same summand -- they're even equal. If you want to test out his statements (which is a good instinct) you have to satisfy all of the hypotheses!

Comment: What do you mean by each term is from a different summand?

Comment: By "summand" I mean - $U_i$. Sorry! Again, I think the thing to do is check how your example fits into the statement of the proposition.

Comment: The first two terms in my example represent the $u_1 - v_1 - w_1$ in the first group of his proof not individual groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes I think the art of teaching is 90% mind reading. The fact is, I'm not well versed in these subtle and powerful techniques to read your mind over the internet, so unfortunately, I can't tell you with any certainty exactly what you've gotten wrong, or what you're missing.

You seem to have slightly misread, or maybe misunderstood, or perhaps you've let your intuition take you further than the text. It would appear that you're familiar with the $n = 2$ case. Let's run through that quickly. Fix any $w \in V$ and suppose $w = u_1 + u_2 = v_1 + v_2$, where $u_i, v_i \in U_i$ for $i = 1, 2$. Then $(u_1 - v_1) + (u_2 - v_2) = w - w = 0$. Since $u_i - v_i \in U_i$ for $i = 1, 2$, it follows, from property $(b)$, that $u_i - v_i = 0$, i.e. $u_i = v_i$, hence the representation of $w$ as a sum of vectors from $U_1$ and $U_2$ is unique. Therefore, the sum is direct.

So, what I *think* you might have done is incorrectly generalised this in your head. The argument on paper notwithstanding, you've noticed, in the crucial part of the argument, the two subtractions of two vectors and generalised it to two subtractions of $n$ vectors. The argument actually involves $n$ subtractions of two vectors.

At this point, I'd probably read the argument again. It's basically the same as the $2$ case. There's not a lot more to it. You get a sum of $(u_1 - v_1) + (u_2 - v_2) + \ldots + (u_n - v_n)$, rather than stopping at $2$. Because of property (b) (which deals with such sums of vectors, each from a different $U_i$, that equal $0$), each $u_i - v_i = 0$, so $u_i = v_i$ and the sum is unique.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I'm still confused on one part. For the vector to be represented uniquely shouldn't it work for $m$ vectors and $n$ subtractions? Also I'm confused what you mean by subtraction and vectors if $(u_1-v_1)$ is a vector and $(u_1-v_1)+(u_2-v_2)+...+(u_n-v_n)$ is the sum then I generalized it to m vectors of $n$ additions.

Comment: No, you need only $2$ subtractions. You're trying to argue that if you have $2$ sums, they are the same. That's all you need to prove uniqueness. To say that a sum is *not* unique is to say that you can find two distinct sums that sum to the same vector. That doesn't assume that there are *only* two ways to sum a vector! Pick any two ways to express it, and they are the same, according to the argument. Therefore, the sum expression is unique.

Comment: Okay I understand know. Even though it's arbitrary I'm interested in how you would prove adding together an odd number of vector spaces such (e.g. $v = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$, $v = b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_n$, $v = c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_n$ is unique because this would give $-v = (a_1 - b_1 - c_1) + (a_2 - b_2 - c_2) + (a_3 - b_3 - c_3)$)

Comment: Well, you could do this, adding/subtracting together more than $2$ representations of the same vector, but I don't really know what you'd be trying to prove.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thanks.